# Pandas timeseries resampling and interpolating together

Tags: pandas, time-series, interpolation, python-3.5

I have timestamped sensor data. Because of technical details, I get data from the sensors at *approximately* one minute intervals. The data may look like this:

```
   tstamp               val
0  2016-09-01 00:00:00  57
1  2016-09-01 00:01:00  57
2  2016-09-01 00:02:23  57
3  2016-09-01 00:03:04  57
4  2016-09-01 00:03:58  58
5  2016-09-01 00:05:00  60
```

Now, essentially, I would be extremely happy if I got all data at the exact minute, but I don't. The only way to conserve the distribution and have data at each minute is to interpolate. For example, between row indexes 1 and 2 there are 83 seconds, and the natural way to get a value at the exact minute is to interpolate between the two rows of data (in this case, it is 57, but that is not the case everywhere).

Right now, my approach is to do the following:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df['measurement_tstamp'].iloc[0].date())
ts_d = df['measurement_tstamp'].dt.hour * 60 * 60 +\
       df['measurement_tstamp'].dt.minute * 60 +\
       df['measurement_tstamp'].dt.second
ts_r = np.arange(0, 24*60*60, 60)
data = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x=ts_d, y=df['speed'].values)(ts_r)
req = pd.Series(data, index=pd.to_timedelta(ts_r, unit='s'))
req.index = date + req.index
```

But this feels rather drawn out and long to me. There are excellent pandas methods that do resampling, rounding, etc. I have been reading them all day, but it turns out that nothing does interpolation just the way I want it. `resample` works like a `groupby` and averages time points that fall together. `fillna` does interpolation, but not after `resample` has already altered the data by averaging.

Am I missing something, or is my approach the best there is?

---

For simplicity, assume that I group the data by day, and by sensor, so only a 24 hour period from one sensor is interpolated at a time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
d = df.set_index('tstamp')
t = d.index
r = pd.date_range(t.min().date(), periods=24*60, freq='T')

d.reindex(t.union(r)).interpolate('index').ix[r]
```

[image]

---

Note, `periods=24*60` works on daily data, not on the sample provided in the question. For that sample, `periods=6` will work.

Comment: But `resample` averages when two or more observations occur in the same group, doesn't it?

Comment: So, this data actually follows a distribution. Essentially, what I want is a linear interpolation between two points, such that the interpolated point falls exactly at the minute. It will never happen with this data that there are more than 2 observations in a minute. In fact, most of the data does fall at the exact minute, but sometimes the sensor pings late, or early. Usually, my colleagues round it to the nearest minute, and fill any missing timestamps with the value from the previous timestamps, but that alters the distribution somewhat. I need more exacting constraints for my problem.

Comment: Nice! However, can you compare this against my solution in the question? I have a dataset (for just September) that is ~114 million records (2,655 sensors, reporting almost 1440 data points each day). I think interpolating at each second will cause it to be slower.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to fix that... still thinking.

Comment: I guess I have to be satisfied with my solution. It is good enough. On a dataset of 6 M rows, it took 20.5 seconds only (partly thanks to `groupby().apply` releasing the GIL)...

Comment: You are a genius! Awesome solution. Simple, and elegant. But, I must make a couple of changes. You see, the timestamp might not start or end exactly at 00:00:00 or 23:59:00. Allow me to edit your answer...

Comment: @Kartik go for it

Answer (score 4):

5 years later, pandas has changed a bit (mostly the `ix` function is deprecated). Anyway, I've rewritten piRSquared's answer to work with current pandas versions and also improved on the date range issue that the answer had:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"tstamp": [
    datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 2, 23),
    datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 3, 4),
    datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 3, 58),
    datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 5, 0)], 
    "val": [57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 60]})


d = df.set_index('tstamp')
t = d.index

r = pd.date_range(t.min(), t.max(), freq='T')

d = d.reindex(t.union(r)).interpolate('index').loc[r]
```

d:

```
                           val
2016-09-01 00:00:00  57.000000
2016-09-01 00:01:00  57.000000
2016-09-01 00:02:00  57.000000
2016-09-01 00:03:00  57.000000
2016-09-01 00:04:00  58.064516
2016-09-01 00:05:00  60.000000
```