# Standardizing timeseries in Pandas using interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, sensors

*First timer, be nice!*

Related to question with slightly different variable types:
[Pandas timeseries resampling and interpolating together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034040/pandas-timeseries-resampling-and-interpolating-together)

I have collected sensor data and the time stamps I have are very irregular, and I want them to be at consistent 1 minute intervals. The only way to conserve the distribution and have data at each minute is to interpolate.

The data set is a million rows long, but this is a header preview (the sensor records in ISO timestamps):

```
   Raw                             DataValue
0 2016-05-01T00:00:59.3+10:00    354.9819946
1 2016-05-01T00:02:59.4+10:00    354.9819946
2 2016-05-01T00:03:59.4+10:00    350.6199951
3 2016-05-01T00:13:00.1+10:00    351.4880066
4 2016-05-01T00:22:00.5+10:00    352.9719849
5 2016-05-01T00:31:01.1+10:00    352.0710144
```

My current code is below, I am using pandas and numpy:

```
data = 
pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Documents/Data/cleaneddata1.csv', 
parse_dates=True)

data['Raw'].index = pd.to_datetime(data['Raw'].index)

d = data.set_index('Raw')
t = d.index
r = pd.date_range(t.min().date(), periods=(len(data)), freq='T')

d.reindex(t.union(r)).interpolate('index').ix[r]
```

It doesn't work, it returns

r = pd.date_range(t.min().date(), periods=(len(data)), freq='T')
     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'

This has been driving me crazy, I am unsure whether the 'str' it refers to is associated with the ISO timestamps.

Comment: only `data['Raw'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Raw'])` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
data['Raw'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Raw'])
```

`Raw` is a column, and `data['Raw']` returns a series, you want to work with that (not its index). Once you're done with that, I'd recommend interpolation with `df.resample`:

```
data = data.set_index('Raw').resample('1min').mean()
```

If you still want to use `interpolate`, you could use `.agg(interpolate)` instead.

---

Since you want to retain the original `Raw` column, you could instead use:

```
data = data.assign(RawDt=pd.to_datetime(data.Raw))\
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='RawDt', freq='1min'))\
       .agg({'DataValue' : 'mean', 'Raw' : 'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: why mean()? Im curious

Comment: @Bharathshetty My understanding of "interpolate".

Comment: @coldspeed thank you!

Only issue is that it is almost getting there, but now not reading the date and time properly. i.e. first line is - 2016-04-30 14:00:00  138.247878 
but the first line should have this date / time layout - 2016-05-01T00:00:59.3+10:00

Comment: @KaitlynSapier When the column is converted to datetime, that information is lost. See edit for alternative solution.

Comment: Amazing! Also, how would i change the interpolation away from mean to instead the log difference between position [2] and position [0] of the DataValue to get DataValue [1] i.e. if DataValue[0] = 19 and DataValue[2] = 20 =>(1+LOG(DataValue[2]/DataValue[1]))*DataValue[1] => DataValue[1] =  19.43

Comment: @wafflecup I'm going to take a shot and say: `data.assign(RawDt=pd.to_datetime(data.Raw))\
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='RawDt', freq='1min')).apply(lambda x: (1 + np.log(x).diff()) * x)` But if this doesn't work, please try opening a new question.